# How to use "Authorize" in Swagger online editor?

Tags: api, swagger, swagger-editor

I am trying to use the swagger online editor http://editor.swagger.io/#/

There is a button called Authorize that opens a dialog where you can provide method of authorization. There are two options

The first is for OAuth2 and the second is for API-Key.

I can't figure out how to use these.

- For OAuth2 authorization, a client ID is required.How does one get a client id?
- For api-key authorization, the editor provides a key called special-key. When I make an API call even without special-key in postman, the API returns a valid response. Is this because the implementation work without keys too?

Comment: Additionally : For the Oauth2 Authorization : The dialog provides a link to the authorization URL. http://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/dialog. Accessing that page results in a 503 unavailable.  Here's my deduction - The Client id should be available on this link that is down.

Comment: Not sure why I'm being downvoted. Perhaps it is because people expect this question to be asked in a swagger forum. The reason I asked is that some reader may understand the nuances of API authorization from the answer. For now I'm stuck but my theory is that I need client id that an authorization server will provide. The scopes will  be used with this client id.  I'll update what I learn once I figure out what's happening.

Comment: Tried with client id form a github oauth app but now attempting authorization shows a validation error " oauth2RedirectUri configuration is not passed. Oauth2 authorization cannot be performed"

Comment: It's still down, a year later.